# How does tomcat know where to find tnsnames.ora

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, tnsnames

I have an oracle database on a server that tomcat is connecting to.

So I have configured in server.xml :

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"  maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/test" password="test" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@test:1111:testdb" username="test"/>
```

tnsnames.ora is locally located on my computer, but I am wondering how is it being registered by tomcat ? I do not see anyrhing in the tomcat xml config files which points to tnsnames.ora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tnsnames.ora file is not consulted at all because you are using the thin driver. If you wanted it to utilize it, you would need to switch to the Oracle OCI driver. You are specifying the host:port:SID already in your connection String. Tomcat does not need the tnsnames file when you do this.

Comment: so why do I need tnsnames.ora if its not being utilized ?

Comment: it depends on what else you are trying to do. If you want to connect with SQLplus, you need it, if you want to use the thick driver (OCI) you need it. Your connection above is JDBC thin which does not consult the tnsnames.ora file at all. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Check the setenv.sh file in bin directory. You can specify the directory where the file tnsnames.ora is found in the JVM parameters:

-Doracle.net.tns_admin=/tomcat/conf/

Comment: So I have to put the tnsnames.ora somewhere on the tomcat and than specify where it is in that file ?